# Hide element to show later - how does the browser update the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, document-ready

Say I have an HTML element on my page that I wish to remain invisible until a certain event happens (e.g. the user clicks on a button). I have the following code in my page:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        ('#messageText').hide();
    }
);
```

The above will execute on document ready and then hide the element. This will allow me to call `show()` later to display it without getting my code entangled with CSS.

My question is **will the user briefly see the element on the page before the above code fires?**

From my testing it appears not, but would users on a slow connection experience a flash of the hidden content? The alternative is that the HTML rendering and the document ready event both happen in the background before the browser updates the screen and that the hidden element is never actually visibly rendered in the UI. Which is it and is it consistent across browser versions and operating systems?

Comment: better to make element's css display to none at first then later you can make it visible

Comment: Add style="display:none;" to the element.

Comment: There is two way you can do it. By using "css style sheet" or through "jquery" on ready. If you use "css style sheet", it will render fast as compare to jquery on slow server connection. I personally dont recommend to use inline styling of elemeny

Comment: You sir can do without a **FOUC** http://www.paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. *$(document).ready()* is fired when DOM is ready - html rendered, js is loaded. You might occur cases when html is rendered quicker than js is loaded - thus you will see your element visible.
p.s. - to avoid such cases it is better to create that element on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the browser will consistently first parse the HTML, CSS and show that. Then potentially it could still take a while for the javascript you mention to run if the `script` tag is for example in the `foot` of the page, is big and user has a slow connection.  Best bet is to give it a style of `display:none;` (either inline or via CSS) before the page loads at all and then either `show` or keep `hidden` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if you are afrraid it might happen just add this to your element :

```
<input id="messageText" type="text" style="display:none;" />
```

or in the css file or tag

```
#messageText{
display:none;
}
```

**PS :** the property `display:none`; has the same effect as `$('#messageText').hide();` only  it happens before  the form is loaded.